# Monitor scaling on nvidia ion

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia

I have an older netbook with Nvidia ION. Because its very slow, i got the idea to install Starcraft on it. Now i'm facing the problem, that the internal chip from the Intel Atom seems to be too slow even for this oldie.

While the external nvidia-chip seems to be fast enough, the game doesn't scale to match the whole monitor and just uses the native size of Starcraft (seems to be 640x480). I use the proprietary nvidia-driver and run Linux Mint 17.2.

Any ideas how i get my GPU to stretch Starcraft on the whole monitor?